Plugin [id: 'kotlin-android'] was not found
I am getting this error when building the project in Flutter. I think it's related to the Kotlin plugin not being found.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\MOTAP ERP\StudioProjects\restaurant\android\app\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'kotlin-android'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/standard_plugins.html for available core plugins)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 877ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Kotlin plugins appear to be installed. I tried the solutions I found on the web.
My app/build gradle and build.gradle file is as follows
app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

android/build.gradle:
buildscript {

        ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.10"

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()


        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

 


How can I solve this problem?

Ensure that you are using the correct Gradle version. Sometimes, mismatched Gradle versions can cause issues. You can specify the Gradle version in your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file. Make sure it matches the version recommended by Flutter.

Also Confirm that the Kotlin version you are using is compatible with your Gradle version

I had exactly the same issue and to solve it, i moved the plugins block outside the pluginManagement block in my settings.gradle file.
Initially, my settings.gradle file looked like this:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

      repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
        id "com.android.application" version "7.4.2" apply false
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
        id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.8.1" apply false
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    }
}

include ":app"

Then i just took plugins block out of pluginManagement block:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

      repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

  
}

  plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
        id "com.android.application" version "7.4.2" apply false
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
        id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.8.1" apply false
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    }

include ":app"

